# Getting the start time of an LSF job

Tags: parsing, deterministic, lsf

One can use `bjobs` to get the start time of an LSF job as such:

```
bjobs -noheader -o start_time $JOB
```

However, this returns low-fidelity (e.g., seconds are not necessarily included) human readable output. Higher (but not necessarily "full", I believe) fidelity output can be parsed out of:

```
bjobs -l $JOB
```

...but that's rather messy. Also, as I alluded to, I think the output can still be ambiguous; the year doesn't always seem to be included here and I don't recall seeing any time zone information.

How can I get an LSF job's start time deterministically and unambiguously (say, as a Unix epoch)?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the seconds are *always* included in `start_time` and the timestamp is exactly the same as the one reported by `bjobs -l $JOBID`.

To show the year in the date, you have to set `LSB_DISPLAY_YEAR=Y` in `lsf.conf`. This is not set by default in LSF.  Don't forget to run `lsadmin reconfig;badmin mbdrestart` after having modified `lsf.conf`.

You can convert dates with `date`:

```
date --date "`bjobs -noheader -o start_time $JOBID`" +"%s"
```

or

```
date --date "$(bjobs -noheader -o start_time $JOBD)" +"%s"
```

if you prefer.